# How to update Jetpack Compose version in a project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to update dependencies to latest version of Jetpack Compose. I tried to change version texts in gradle files but build error. Also I can't find what is the latest version of Jetpack Compose.

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.android'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha11'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

I tried and searched on internet for two days but always build error.I'm very noob at this jobs, so it didn't work.

Comment: "I tried to change version texts in gradle files but build error" -- we cannot help you without the actual error. "I can't find what is the latest version of Jetpack Compose" -- the simplest solution is to use [the Compose BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup). Regardless, you can see the latest versions of the Compose artifacts [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose#versions).

Answer (score 2):

Jetpack compose has switched to using a bill of materials (BOM) to combine compatible library versions.
Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom):

```
dependencies {
    // Import the Compose BOM
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')

    // Import other Compose libraries without version numbers
    implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation'
}
```

You can find the latest BOM version [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping).

If you are still getting build errors then you most likely need to update your kotlin plugin version.